# jQuery based HTML interactive flipbook plugin

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a flip book style way of presenting HTML content.

There are plenty of Jquery flipboks like these

[Jquery Flip Book Demos](http://codecanyon.net/item/3d-flipbook-responsive-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/3946817)

However you can not interact with the pages..only flip them. I want to place HTML into the pages and clickable images. Does anyone know where I can find such a plugin, free or premium?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to click the images? And HTML is already in those page since jQuery is acting upon them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for something like the "[Experimental Page Layout Inspired by Flipboard.](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/07/experimental-page-layout-inspired-by-flipboard/)"

DEMO: http://tympanus.net/Development/FlipboardPageLayout/

SOURCE CODE: http://tympanus.net/Development/FlipboardPageLayout/FlipboardPageLayout.zip